# Animation render blurry issue

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, motion-blur

I made a short scrolling gallery animation. I didn't use motion blur, but when I rendered the animation, I found the video is so blurry while playing.

I tried everything I can to solve the problem, but I am totally new to Blender and what I googled doesn't help much.

Any advise as to what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ow7hjy9Wo-eqEFFyQP8BsSdEFfKBlevb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I would suspect this is caused by the encoding settings of the video.

Comment: @RobertGützkow, thank you for the suggestion. With your advice, I did some changes to the encoding settings, like [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/xKhv2N4s9NAEsUaA7). But the rendered video still looks as blurry as it was, like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q5WWz5aTTC-7l6cwHqpe5sgvY0vOr7qr/view?usp=sharing). Would you mind be more detailed about what video encoding settings I need to change?